# Averaging 3-Dimensional Array

Tags: matlab

I have an image array (width, height, rgb) and I want to compute the average R, G, and B values of the image.

How do I find the mean of the 3-dimensional array so that I get the vector [avg_r, avg_g, avg_b]?

Answer (score 1):

First reshape the array from 3 dimensions to 2 dimensions, so in reshaped array each column represents a color.

Then average along the first dimension:

```
reshaped_img = reshape(img, width* height , 3);
avg = mean(reshaped_img)  %same as   avg = mean(reshaped_img, 1)
```